# Keras reported accuracy doesn't correspond with model.predict()

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**Relevant portions of my code:**

Model Architecture:

```
Sequential(
    layers=[
        BatchNormalization(input_shape=input_shape),
        LSTM(lstm_1, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout_1),
        BatchNormalization(),
        LSTM(lstm_2, dropout=dropout_2),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ]
)
```

**Compile and fit calls:**

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                            optimizer=RMSprop(0.0005),
                            metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.stack(data_train['spectrogram']), np.stack(data_train['label']),
          batch_size=512,
          epochs=50,
          validation_data=(np.stack(data_test['spectrogram']), np.stack(data_test['label'].values)))
```

**When training**

```
Epoch 50/50
466/466 [==============================] - 4s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5264 - acc: 0.7425 - val_loss: 0.8254 - val_acc: 0.5339
```

**But when I do**

```
train_preds = np.round(model.predict(np.stack(data_train['spectrogram']))).astype('int32')
```

**The train_preds are around 55% accurate, however, as shown above, the reported accuracy on the last epoch is 0.7425**

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there some explanation?

I'll be happy to post more of the code, if that helps.

Comment: Sometimes 55% accuracy is too much. Explain a bit about what's the problem, what's the clue, what's your guess.

Comment: The issue is that Keras says training accuracy is 0.7425, while model.predict shows 55%.

Comment: You need to tell us your model code and compile call for any answer to be meaningful.

Comment: I've added the model and compile codes.

Comment: You have to provide the context, what are the inputs and what do you try to predict?

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy shown in the **epochs is the accuracy of the model on the training dataset you provided**. And the `model.predict` **shows the accuracy on the validation dataset**. The **0.7 accuracy is on the training dataset** and the **0.55 accuracy is on the test/validation dataset**.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am `model.predict`ing on the train dataset itself. So the accuracies should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your 74% is on the **Training Set**, this is an indicator of own is performing your algorithm while training, you should never look at it as a reference.

You should always look at your **Test Set**, this is the real value that matters.

Fore more, your accuracies should always look like this (at least the style):

e.g. The training set accuracy always growing and the testing set following the same trend but below the training curve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When training accuracy/loss is *high* but dev/test accuracy/loss is *low*, It clearly gives a signal of **overfitting**. If you plot your accuracy for training and testing data, you probably have something similar to the following picture:

[image]

At some point in your plot, training accuracy is decreased but test accuracy is not. *What can be done*?

1. Early Stopping
2. Regularization
3. Train with more data
4. Simplify your model (fewer parameters)

**Clue**: Based on your code, you have two LSTM and 466 training examples. LSTM model is relatively a powerful network and can easily overfit on the data. Decrease hidden layer size of LSTM or remove one of them may be a good starting point to avoid overfitting.